# Send mouse click whenever you move the mouse, javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im totally new in js, I want to know whether it is possible to send a random screen mouse click in a site, everytime the user moves the mouse.

For ex. I browse whateversite.com. Once page is loaded i randomly move the mouse down, I want a random screen click.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: onmousemove and Trigger a mouse click. Search for events javascript with these keywords.

Comment: ... and before that, https://www.google.com/search?q=user+script

Comment: Thank you Nevin, im working on it :)